# Show that $E (\delta)$ is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $E $ be compact.For $\delta > 0$ let $E (\delta)$ be the set of points which have distance less than $\delta $ to at least one of the points in $E$. Show that $E (\delta)$ is measurable.

How can I proceed? Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT** $:$

It is clear that $E (\delta) \subset B (x;\delta)$ for some $x \in E$. Can it help in proving this fact?

Comment: If *less than* means $<\delta$ then $E(\delta)$ is open, if it means $\le \delta$ then it is closed. In both cases it is thus Borel measurable.

Comment: How do you show that $E (\delta)$ is open for strictly less than case?

Comment: If $d(x,e) < \delta$, then also $d(y,e) < \delta$ where $d(x,y) < \delta - d(x,e)$.

Comment: Thanks.I got it.